# Phantom column in Tkinter Treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

How can I make the phantom column visible the indices of my dataframe at the phantom column when I initialize my tree with the following code? I mean column #0.

```
tree = ttk.Treeview(root)
 tree["column"]=list(df.columns)
    tree["show"]="headings"
    for column in tree["column"]:
        tree.heading(column, text=column)
    df_rows=df.to_numpy().tolist()
    for row in df_rows:
        tree.insert("", "end", values=row)
tree.pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `width` option of `Treeview.column`

```
tree.column('#0', width=0, stretch='no')
```

This doesn't remove the column unfortunately, you just can't see it because it has no width. You can still resize the column to be visible, after which you can't resize it to be invisible again. If you would like to prevent the user from resizing the column, use the following:

```
def dont_resize(event):
    if table.identify_region(event.x, event.y) == "separator":
        return "break"

tree.bind('<1>', dont_resize)
tree.bind('<Motion>', dont_resize)
```

Typically I write event handlers as a private method of my GUI class, so it would look something like this:

```
class Table(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self)
        self.tree.pack()

        self._config()

    def _config(self):
        cols = ['Column A', 'Column B', 'Column C']
        self.tree['columns'] = cols

        for col in cols:
            self.tree.heading(col, text=col)
        self.tree.column('#0', width=0, stretch='no')

        self.tree.bind('<1>', self._dont_resize)
        self.tree.bind('<Motion>', self._dont_resize)

    def _dont_resize(self, event):
        if self.tree.identify_region(event.x, event.y) == 'separator':
            return 'break'
```

Comment: Where should I add the code you offer djugren?

Comment: @mdiramali Edited my answer to show how to use it

Comment: Thank you @djugren, that worked. Now, I can see the phantom column. But how can I add the indices of my dataframe to the phantom column= I thought it will be initialized automatically.